# How to wrap execve system call?

Tags: exec, wrapper, system-calls

I want to wrap `execve` system call. I wrote the following code to start with. But whenever I use it. I get segmentation fault core-dump.

```
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  #define _GNU_SOURCE
  #include <dlfcn.h>
  #include <string.h>


  static int (*real_execve)(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[])=0;

 int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[],
       char *const envp[])
 {
     printf("intercepted %s \n", filename);
     return real_execve(filename, argv, envp);
 }
```

Comment: Can you share the complete code. Were you able to analyze the program's coredump with gdb ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the real_execve function pointer to the "real" one at the top of your function.

```
if (!real_execve) {
    real_execve = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "execve");
}
```

As you have it now, real_execve is never set, so you're calling a null pointer which crashes.